# Automatically add column based on a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a question, i have 50 meters long rail alignment. I can distribute that alignment depend on the space, for instance i distribute the alignment every 10 meters to the columns. Looks like this;

```
Column A: Column B:   Column C:  Column D:    Column E:      Column F:
 0         10             20          30           40            50
```

Also i have location of the rail variable. I want to distribute the 50 meters long alignment every 10 meters space into the columns and i want to add rail location to the 21 m. Looks like this.

```
Column A: Column B:   Column C:  Column D:    Column E:      Column F: Column G:
  0         10             20          21         30           40            50
```

I mean when i enter the value of location of the rail to the cell, excel must control that value and add a new column if it is not exist on excel sheet. .must be look like above.

Is it possible to do that? thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you can sort data left to right to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

You do not mention where you input data. If you enter data end of previous data then use following sub.

```
Sub AddColumn()
Dim LastClmn
LastClmn = Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Address

    Range("A1:" & LastClmn).Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A1:" & LastClmn), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:" & LastClmn)
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlLeftToRight
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

(1) Existing data

[image]

(2) Add new data

[image]

(3) After running the sub (I used Command Button).

[image]

Comment: You can achieve same by manual sort. If you enter data in another cell, suppose you are entering data in `D5` cell, then you have to customize above sub.